# Jensen inequality

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Does Jensen inequality, which is $\mathbb{E}(g(x)) \geq g(\mathbb{E}X)$ if $g$ is convex, assume that $\mathbb{E}X$ (expected value of random variable $X$) must belong to $R(X)$ (range of random variable $X$)?

I THANK YOU.

Comment: No. $\phantom{a}$

Comment: Why do you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative: consider the easy example $X:\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}\rightarrow R(X)=\{x_1,x_2\}$, with $X(\omega_i)=x_i$ and $P(X=x_1)=p$, $P(X=x_2)=1-p$.

Then, for any  convex $g$:

$$g(p x_1+(1-p)x_2)=g(E[X])\leq p g(x_1)+(1-p)g(x_2)=E[g(X)].$$

Note that $E[X]\not\in R(X)$, which is no linear space. It is just a finite set.